# Additional Tools for Xcode 13.1 missing

Tags: xcode

On the apple developer download page (https://developer.apple.com/download/all/), there is no Additional Tools for Xcode 13.1.

Can Additional Tools for Xcode 13 be used instead with Xcode 13.1?

Answer (score 1):

`Additional Tools for Xcode` contains multiple tools. You need to try it yourself. In my case, I need `Network Link Container`. The version 13 is not work(`Could not load Network Link Conditioner Preferences Pane`), but version 13.2 works.